# How to send users email based on zip code proximity using rules in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, location, email

I'm looking for a way to send email notices to my users, based on zip code proximity, whenever a content type is created. I've tried using rules but can't seem to find an action based on the location module. I have the zip code database installed and can use Views to create a view with the info.

Can Views Send be automated by rules to send the emails? Or is there another way?

Total noob here but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but someone has asked something similar before. I'm trying to solve this type of problem too and came upon:

[Rules & Proximity](https://www.drupal.org/node/941130)

and [How To Use Rules with Proximity](https://www.drupal.org/node/919316)

But these links were for Drupal 6 so not sure if it will work for Drupal 7.